# Is it possible to add Google single sign on to specific 365 users, NOT the whole tenant?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, google, single-sign-on

We've got a client with a satellite office outside of the US, and it's not connected to their AD server. As such, changes to their 365 passwords are not synced like the home office does, and it gets to be a real hassle when they're trying to login and/or reset their passwords.

So, we'd like those satellite 365 users to be able to log in with with their Google credentials to make things easier. We DON'T want to enable SSO for the whole tenant, however. How can we do it just for this small group of 3-5 users?

Unfortunately, they do NOT have Azure AD Premium or 365 Premium, so we can't even start with conditional access policies.

Please advise?

Comment: hows about to use a azure sync client to sync the password instead trying a non possible (imho) work around?

Comment: Agreed. Why not just create user accounts in the on premises AD for these users and sync them to Office 365 like you do for the rest of the users?

Comment: @joeqwerty There is no on premises AD for those users, unfortunately.

Comment: @djdomi Can that be installed on just their own machines, in case they also work from home (which is sometimes the case)?

Comment: They don't need to have their own AD. Create them in your AD. The only purpose is so that you can sync their passwords to Office 365. They won't actually log into your AD with those accounts.

Comment: The Sync Client will be mostly installed on the ADS-Server